# Including Inheritance and Polymorphism into Flood-It Game

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to finish my final project for computer science class. We use java in class and I'm fairly familiar with its controls/concepts. I have made a version of the game flood-it however the requirements for the assignment are OOP, inheritance/interfaces and polymorphism. I already have the other components and my game works but I'm not sure how to include those ones. Also, sometimes it glitches and doesn't switch random squares that should be switched but i cant find any issues

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class FloodIt implements ActionListener
{
    Font clicksFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
   Font promptFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
   Font newGameFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 25);
   Font titleFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC, 40);

   JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane, main, grid, colours;
    JLabel prompt, clicks, result, title;
   JButton yellow, orange, cyan, pink, green, magenta, newGame;

   Random rand = new Random();

   String[] grids = {"cyanmini.jpg", "greenmini.png", "magentamini.jpg", "orangemini.png", "pinkmini.jpg", "yellowmini.png"};
   JLabel[][] coloursArray = new JLabel[14][14];
   int numClicks = 0; 
   boolean filled = false;

   public FloodIt()
    {
      //Create and set up the frame
      frame = new JFrame("Flood-It");
      frame.setBounds(600,100,10,10);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      //Create a content pane jpanel
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBackground(new Color(210,250,230));
      contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,50,20,50));
      contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


      //////////////////////////////////////////////

      //Create a new main jpanel
      main = new JPanel();
      main.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      main.setBackground(new Color(210,250,230));
      main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(670, 225));
      main.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(670, 225));
      main.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(670, 225));
      contentPane.add(main);

       //Create, and add label to main jpanel
      title = new JLabel("F L O O D - I T");
      title.setFont(titleFont);
      title.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      main.add(title);

      //Create, and add label to main jpanel
      prompt = new JLabel("Click a colour button to change the flood colour. Fill the board with a single colour.");
      prompt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      prompt.setFont(promptFont);
      main.add(prompt);

      //Create, and add label to main jpanel
      clicks = new JLabel(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
      clicks.setFont(clicksFont);
      clicks.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 15));
      main.add(clicks);

      //Create, and add label to main jpanel
      result = new JLabel("");
      result.setFont(clicksFont);
      result.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 15));
      main.add(result);

      //Creates a button and adds to main jpanel
        newGame = new JButton("New Game");
      newGame.setFont(newGameFont);
      newGame.setActionCommand("newGame");
      newGame.addActionListener(this);
      main.add(newGame);

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////

      //Create a grid jpanel
      grid = new JPanel();
      grid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
      grid.setBackground(new Color(210,250,230));
      grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(14,14,0,0));
      grid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
      grid.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
      grid.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
      contentPane.add(grid);

      for (int r=0; r < 14; r++) 
      {
         for (int c=0; c < 14; c++) 
         {
            coloursArray[r][c]= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(grids[rand.nextInt(6)]));
            grid.add(coloursArray[r][c]);
         }
      }


      ///////////////////////////////////////////////

      //Create a new colours jpanel
      colours = new JPanel();
      colours.setBackground(new Color(210,250,230));
      colours.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,50,20,50));
      contentPane.add(colours);

      //Creates a button
        yellow = new JButton(new ImageIcon("yellow.png"));
        yellow.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      yellow.setActionCommand("yellow");
      yellow.addActionListener(this);
      yellow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(yellow);

      //Creates a button
        orange = new JButton(new ImageIcon("orange.png"));
        orange.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      orange.setActionCommand("orange");
      orange.addActionListener(this);
      orange.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(orange);

      //Creates a button
        cyan = new JButton(new ImageIcon("cyan.jpg"));
        cyan.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      cyan.setActionCommand("cyan");
      cyan.addActionListener(this);
      cyan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(cyan);

      //Creates a button
        pink = new JButton(new ImageIcon("pink.jpg"));
        pink.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      pink.setActionCommand("pink");
      pink.addActionListener(this);
      pink.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(pink);

      //Creates a button
        green = new JButton(new ImageIcon("green.png"));
        green.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      green.setActionCommand("green");
      green.addActionListener(this);
      green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(green);

      //Creates a button
        magenta = new JButton(new ImageIcon("magenta.jpg"));
        magenta.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      magenta.setActionCommand("magenta");
      magenta.addActionListener(this);
      magenta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));
        colours.add(magenta);

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////

      //Add content pane to frame
      frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

      //Size and then display the frame.
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   private void changeSurrounding(int row, int col, String nColour, String oColour)
   {
      if(row < 14 && col < 14)
      {
         if(String.valueOf(coloursArray[row][col].getIcon()).equals(oColour))
         {
            if(nColour.equals("yellowmini.png"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("yellowmini.png"));
            }
            else if(nColour.equals("orangemini.png"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("orangemini.png"));
            }
            else if(nColour.equals("greenmini.png"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("greenmini.png"));
            }
            else if(nColour.equals("pinkmini.jpg"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("pinkmini.jpg"));
            }
            else if(nColour.equals("cyanmini.jpg"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("cyanmini.jpg"));
            }
            else if(nColour.equals("magentamini.jpg"))
            {
               coloursArray[row][col].setIcon(new ImageIcon("magentamini.jpg"));
            }

            changeSurrounding(row+1,col, nColour, oColour);
            changeSurrounding(row,col+1, nColour, oColour);
         }
      }
   }

   //Does actions according to which button has been clicked.
   //Pre: none
   //Post:Apropriate actions have been done
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
      String eventName = event.getActionCommand();
      String newColour;
      String oldColour = String.valueOf(coloursArray[0][0].getIcon());
      int total = 0;     

      for (int r=0; r < 14; r++) 
      {
         for (int c=0; c < 14; c++) 
         {
            if(String.valueOf(coloursArray[r][c].getIcon()).equals(String.valueOf(coloursArray[0][0].getIcon())))
            {
               total+=1;
            }
         }
      }

      if(total == 194)
      {
         filled = true;
      }
      else
      {
         filled = false;

      } 

      if (eventName.equals("yellow"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         newColour = "yellowmini.png";
         changeSurrounding(0, 0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won :)");
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost :(");
            }
         }            
      }
      else if (eventName.equals("orange"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         newColour = "orangemini.png";
         changeSurrounding(0,0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won!");  
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost");
            }
         }                
      }
      else if (eventName.equals("cyan"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         newColour = "cyanmini.jpg";
         changeSurrounding(0,0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won!"); 
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost");
            }
         }             
      }
      else if (eventName.equals("pink"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         newColour = "pinkmini.jpg";
         changeSurrounding(0, 0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won!");
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost");
            }
         }      
      }
      else if (eventName.equals("green"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30"); 
         newColour = "greenmini.png";
         changeSurrounding(0,0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won!");
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost");
            }
         }   
      }
      else if (eventName.equals("magenta"))
      {
         numClicks+=1;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         newColour = "magentamini.jpg";
         changeSurrounding(0,0, newColour, oldColour);

         if(numClicks >= 30)
         {
            yellow.setVisible(false);
            orange.setVisible(false);
            pink.setVisible(false);
            magenta.setVisible(false);
            green.setVisible(false);
            cyan.setVisible(false);

            if(filled == true && numClicks == 30)
            {
               result.setText("You Won!");
            }
            else
            {
               result.setText("You Lost");
            }
         }
      }
      else if(eventName.equals("newGame"))
      {
         numClicks = 0;
         clicks.setText(String.valueOf(numClicks) +"/30");
         result.setText("");

         for (int r=0; r < 14; r++) 
         {
            for (int c=0; c < 14; c++) 
            {
               grid.remove(coloursArray[r][c]);
               coloursArray[r][c]= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(grids[rand.nextInt(6)]));
               grid.add(coloursArray[r][c]);
            }
         } 

         yellow.setVisible(true);
         orange.setVisible(true);
         pink.setVisible(true);
         magenta.setVisible(true);
         green.setVisible(true);
         cyan.setVisible(true);


      }
   }  


    private static void runGUI()
   {
      JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      FloodIt start = new FloodIt();
   }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to write your own Interface you already implemented the ActionListener Interface. So to add Polymorphism and Inheritance you need to split your FloodIt Class. Go for the Model, View and Controller pattern. After you did that it will be more easy to realize the required approaches. You could do an Abstract Square Superclass and then do different colored Subclasses of it. After that you could put the Squares in a 2D Array and then call methods depending which Colored Square is called. In this way you implemented both Inheritance and Polymorphism because the methods are chosen at Runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure where that would fit in though, what would the array be used for and what methods would it contain?